# How do I disable NuGet from running when I build

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have a customer who must build our software at their site, but the group policy prevents nuget from running.  This causes the build to fail.  All of the packages already exist within the project (stored in version control), so there is no need for NuGet to even run.

Is there a way to prevent NuGet.exe from running?

Comment: Hi Erik, did you build this solution inside VS or through command/script and could you please share the detail error message when the build is failed? Please check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#enabling-and-disabling-package-restore and disable package restore through configure the NuGet.Config file. Before disable it, please make sure your local solution already have all required packages.

Answer (score 2):

NuGet.exe is never run manually, so if it's running, you can change your build script to stop calling it. Visual Studio 2010, 2012 and 2013 had a feature to "Enable NuGet Package Restore on Solution", which would download a NuGet.Targets file and NuGet.exe, save it into a `.nuget` directory and modify every .NET project file to import the `nuget.targets` file. If your project is a carry over from these times, you should remove those changes as Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019 have better integrated support for NuGet. However, in those cases you will need to make sure that any build script that runs on CI does a separate nuget restore, as it will no longer happen automatically as part of a MSBuild build.

In Visual Studio 2015 onwards, in Tools->Options, NuGet Package Manager->General there is an option "Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio" which you can turn off.

[image: NuGet Package Manager options in Visual Studio, with "Automatically Check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio" circled.]

With the dotnet cli, you can use the `--no-restore` option on commands that might implicitly restore.

Comment: I have unchecked both Package Restore options, but I am still getting "All packages listed in packages.config are already installed." when I build, which leads me to believe that NuGet is still running.  When I directed the customer to uncheck these boxes, they received the same error that NuGet.exe was prevented from running due to group policies.

Comment: If they have customised their MSBuild files to run NuGet.exe, or used that VS2010/2012/2013 feature I mentioned, they'll need to edit the files again to disable it. New projects from the built-in templates do not. Without being able to see the files and the build myself, it's impossible to guess why it's happening.